# Angular selected according to different model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, angularjs-ng-repeat

What i want to do is, if the right side of the column `(select)` has any data that is given on the left side of the column, it has to be selected automatically.

If there is a `Germany` data on the left side, the right side, which is `select`, has to be updated.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QzjF3qBAa9YAPyS4h3lq?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

On init you should find a value of the city form right side text `ng-init="rawSelect = (vm.cities| filter: {Text: city.Text})[0]"` then Also do change track by for selecting option on init it should be `track by po.Text`

**Markup**

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="city in vm.cities">
      <td>{{city.Text}}</td>
      <td ng-init="rawSelect = (vm.cities| filter: {Text: city.Text})[0]" >
        <select data-ng-model="rawSelect" data-ng-options="po.Text for po in vm.selectCity track by po.Text">
          <option value="">Match later</option>
        </select>
        <pre>{{rawSelect}}</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cx29AI6nbFzLOvLa3nG9?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: This is what i have been looking for so far. Let me ask you another question, is there a way to do it via controller function?

Comment: yes, you could do filtering from controller, only you need to call controller function using `ng-init` & that method will do filtering using `$filter`

Comment: @agriboz try this http://plnkr.co/edit/22xMPBIAzjOYhyYFePLN?p=preview & please do upvote if it does helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: i would like to know if there is a way to do track by `ID` instead of text. Is it possible to match it via `option label not option value`. Option value could be value of cities `ID`.

Comment: @agriboz I'll let you know..I need to do some fiddling

Comment: And the right column gives the wrong id. i.e. `Portugal` should have `21` not `2`. It still uses the `cities` model not `selectCity` model.